# Create NuGet package with a scaffolding only

Tags: nuget-package, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have a question, I would like to create a nuget Package, wich only include a custom scaffolding template.

I know how I create a custom scaffolding, but I do it ever in an existing mvc project, but now I want to create NuGet package, so that I can install the package on my projects and don't have to create or copy the complete scaffolding template.

Can someone help me?

Best regards

Comment: There is a great walkthrough here: http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/07/14/leverage-t4scaffolding-for-wcf-web-api.aspx The associated code is available here:
http://webapiscaffolding.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Malgaur is correct the [article](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/07/14/leverage-t4scaffolding-for-wcf-web-api.aspx) he posted is a great way to handle this. I am currently working on a solution. You will need to host your own Nuget packages, but that is just a matter of putting them into a shared directory and add it as a Nuget source.